# Binding Watson Services to a Kube Cluster in IBM Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to bind a service (using cluster-service-bind) and receive an error message. The command and the error message is provided below:

```
ibmcloud cs cluster-service-bind <ClusterID> prod conversation-service-12tg
```

Binding service instance to namespace...

**FAILED**

This IBM Cloud service does not support the Cloud Foundry service keys API and cannot be added to your cluster. Select a different service, and try again   (E0022)
Incident ID: 80634d1a-356e-4369-aa2c-f6f01297fec7

I can bind another service such as CloudantNoSQL without any issues.

Is this error related to the move to [IAM keys that Watson Services](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-iam.html) made in late May 2018?

Any suggestion(s) on how to bind these services and use them in Kube apps?

Answer (score 1):

If you're still having this issue, log into the console UI. Your account should auto-sync.

This is a known issue for which a fix was recently submitted.

Comment: Please open an issue in IBM Cloud.